# Git fetch and merge skipped asking me for conflicts

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, fetch

I am using Intellij and I want to put the latest changes from a remote branch B to branch A. branch A is the master branch.

After I git fetch and merge branch B, which have files having conflict with branch A, it didn't ask me for my decision of what to do with the conflicts and have "use theirs" for all conflicts automatically.

I remembered if I do "merge branch X" only without doing git fetch, it will ask for my decision for every single conflict.

What caused these problems? Am I doing getting changes from remote branch wrongly?

Comment: Whether or not you fetch should generally have no effect on the merge strategy.  But I don't know how to merge with `use theirs` from IntelliJ.  I would do this from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you fetch, make sure to merge `origin/B`, not `B` itself.

Second, a merge uses theirs only if there is no concurrent changes since the last common ancestor.

```
 a--x--a (A)
     \           
      b--b (B)  
          \    
           b--b (`origin/B`, just fetched)
```

A merge won't have any conflict if the files merges since commit x have only changes in `origin/B`

```
 a--x--a----------M (A, merge commit)
     \           /
      b--b (B)  /
          \    /
           b--b (origin/B, just fetched)
```

Comment: do u mean that if all files changed in branch B aren't changed in branch A, there wont hv conflict in merge?
What i get now is after a common ancestor C,  B changed X.html (added n lines), A also changed X.html (added m lines), after the merge, the m lines were gone without conflicts asked.

Comment: @UchihaJavaraa yes: if those files have not changed in A since the last common ancestor (here 'x'), then there is no conflict, and changes from B are reported onto A.